# Dividing in complex analysis task

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm over confused about dividing in complex analysis and couldn't find any good examples.

if $z=3−4i$ and $w=7i+6$

How do you calculate a simple $z/w$?

Comment: Hint: multiply by the conjugate of the denominator.

Comment: $\frac{3-4i}{6+7i}=a+bi$ has a unique solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try always to multiply by the conjugate of the denominator and divide by it, too:

$$\frac zw=\frac zw\cdot\frac{\overline w}{\overline w}=\frac{z\overline w}{|w|^2}\implies$$

$$\frac{3-4i}{6+7i}\cdot\frac{6-7i}{6-7i}=\frac{18-28-(21+24)i}{6^2+7^2}=-\frac{10}{85}-\frac{45}{85}i=-\frac2{17}-\frac9{17}i$$

Answer (score 1):

You have

$$\frac{3-4i}{7i+6}=\frac{(3-4i)(6-7i)}{7^2+6^2}=\frac{-10-45i}{85}=-\frac{10}{85}-\frac 9{17}i.$$

Basically, you always need to do:

$$\frac zw=\frac{z\overline w}{w\overline w}.$$